# Tabular appearance when using listing in beamer

Tags: beamer, listings

I am using the listing package to display some code. However, the result is not what I expected due to the annoying presence of symbols ^^| (see picture below). [image]

The settings that I am using are the following

```
\lstset{
  language={Mosel},
  basicstyle=\mytextsizesmaller, % Global Code Style
  captionpos=b, % Position of the Caption (t for top, b for bottom)
  extendedchars=true, % Allows 256 instead of 128 ASCII characters
  tabsize=2, % number of spaces indented when discovering a tab 
  columns=fixed, % make all characters equal width
  keepspaces=true, % does not ignore spaces to fit width, convert tabs to spaces
  showstringspaces=false, % lets spaces in strings appear as real spaces
  breaklines=true, % wrap lines if they don't fit
  frame=trbl, % draw a frame at the top, right, left and bottom of the listing
  frameround=tttt, % make the frame round at all four corners
  framesep=4pt, % quarter circle size of the round corners
  numbers=left, % show line numbers at the left
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray}, % style of the line numbers
  commentstyle=\color{airforceblue}, % style of comments
  keywordstyle=\color{magenta}, % style of keywords
  stringstyle=\color{orange(colorwheel)}, % style of strings
  showtabs=false, 
  showspaces=false
}
```

I observe that the ^^| symbols appear in correspondence to tabulars. This is why I inserted showtabs=false, showspaces=false in the settings. The result however is not as expected. Any suggestion to remove the problem?

Comment: Please make a minimal working example which shows us which fonts and font encodings you use